# PHP database query display in html

Tags: php, html, mysql, post

Im not a hardvore coder. Im learning php/htmp/mysql/css now :)

So, i make mysql query with php, and now i want display the query result in a html table. But i don't know, how can i transfer variables between php and html code.

My php file now look like this:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("my_db_host","my_db_username","my_db_pass","my_db_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM hlstats_Servers
WHERE serverId='2'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$name=$row['name'];
$ip=$row['address'] . ":" . $row['port'];
$player=$row['act_players'] . "/" . $row[max_players];
$map=$row['act_map'];
}    

mysqli_close($con);
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>$name</td>
              </tr>
        </table>

        <table>
              <tr>
                  <td>Ip cím:</td>
                  <td>$ip</td>
              </tr>
              <tr> 
                  <td>Jelenlegi pálya:</td>
                  <td>$map</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td>Játékosok</td>
                  <td>$player</td>
              </tr> 
          </table>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of just placing the variable name (e.g. `$name`) use `<?php echo $name; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sok sikert (good luck) :)

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("my_db_host", "my_db_username", "my_db_pass", "my_db_name");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query(
        $con,
        "SELECT * FROM hlstats_Servers
        WHERE serverId='2'"
    );
?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
                <?php $name = $row['name']; ?>
                <?php $ip = $row['address'] . ":" . $row['port']; ?>
                <?php $player = $row['act_players'] . "/" . $row['max_players']; ?>
                <?php $map = $row['act_map']; ?>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ip cím:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $ip; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jelenlegi pálya:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $map; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Játékosok</td>
                    <td><?php echo $player; ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

<?php mysqli_close($con); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "transfer" variables from the PHP code to the HTML code, because the latter is not a programming language, it is only a structured markup language describing a webpage without variables or procedures.

Instead, you can show the current value of a PHP variable, and then the HTML markup will contain the actual value of that variable. For example:

```
<table>
      <tr>
          <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```